# AWS Lambda not returning list of alarms

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a small node.js lambda in AWS (see code below). When it runs, it reports "success", but does not print a list of CloudWatch alarms as I would expect it to.

The [AWS Javascript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html) leads me to believe what I'm doing should work. We do have a number of alarms setup, so I'm a bit at a loss for why the lambda is not listing the names of all of the alarms.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

```js
//generated from TypeScript

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

function handler(event, context) {
  var cw = new AWS.CloudWatch();
  var params = {};
  cw.describeAlarms(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ', err);
    }
    data.MetricAlarms.forEach(function(alarm) {
      console.log('Alarm: ', alarm.AlarmName);
    });
  });
  context.succeed("Success");
}
exports.handler = handler;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two potential issues to check.  I was able to use your code and describe alarms after verifying both of the following were correct:

### context.succeed is Incorrectly Scoped

Your `context.succeed` method is incorrectly scoped -- since it occurs right after `describeAlarms` outside the scope of its response, it is being processed right after you make the request without waiting for it to complete.

Move it into your callback scope, like this:

```
  cw.describeAlarms(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ', err);
    }
    data.MetricAlarms.forEach(function(alarm) {
      console.log('Alarm: ', alarm.AlarmName);
    });

    context.succeed("Success");
  });
```

### Lambda Execution Role

Your lambda's execution role will need permission to talk to the CloudWatch API. Execution roles are IAM roles that define what AWS services your lambda can interact with.

A good place to start would be to attach a managed CloudWatch Read Only Access policy, and then whittle down your required permissions down from there:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "autoscaling:Describe*",
        "cloudwatch:Describe*",
        "cloudwatch:Get*",
        "cloudwatch:List*",
        "logs:Get*",
        "logs:Describe*",
        "logs:TestMetricFilter",
        "sns:Get*",
        "sns:List*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Compute Blog - Everything Depends on Context or, The Fine Art of nodejs Coding in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/getting-nodejs-and-lambda-to-play-nicely/)
- [AWS Documentation - AWS Lambda Permissions Model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html)
- [AWS Documentation - AWS Managed (Predefined) Policies for CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/iam-identity-based-access-control-cw.html#managed-policies-cloudwatch)

Comment: Getting the roles setup properly did the trick. Looks like I've spent too much time in C# lately, thanks for pointing out the scoping mistake!